# MySql Regexp to search from user input

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This one is killing me,i'm a total noob with regex.
Im trying to make a site search and compare the entered text with the titles column in the 
database.
Basically what i want to accomplish with regex is **LIKE '%word1 word2 word3%'** , but with some string variatons.

For example :

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP
>   'w[ao]rd'

works just fine. It looks for word and ward. But when i want multiple words it returns nothing.

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP
>   'w[ao]rd sec[or]nd th[io]rd'

I don't want to search for word OR second OR third i want to have them all in the title,just like in the upper case with LIKE.

I was thinking maybe to explode the search string the user inputs then in a foreach do a regexp word by word,but don't know how to concatenate all of the variations into one query.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that im searching in a utf8_unicode_ci collated table.
So really im trying to do a [cčć]orak type of search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP 'w[ao]rd|sec[or]nd|th[io]rd'
```

edit:

"okay so you want them to all be in the title and in that order?"

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP 'w[ao]rd.*sec[or]nd.*th[io]rd'
```

This will look for those words (and the variations) and make them be in that order, so for example

```
word blahblah second more blah third
```

Comment: thanks,but this is doing OR,and i said i don't need it that way.

Comment: well  there are other ways to do it, like doing "where title regexp '..' OR ... but it still boils down to using some kind of OR syntax...because..how else do you expect to say "look for this OR this" ? That's the whole point of OR type syntax.

Comment: ok i get that,but i tought this can be accomplished in one regexp code. So basically if u search for 'big red apple' i want it only to find sentences that have these words in the same order,and not big OR red OR apple.

Comment: okay so you want them to all be in the title and in that order? see edit

Comment: yupp. but it looks like i found what was the problem. Very interesting indeed. Utf8 was making all the trouble.